# Deploying Docker Container Registry on Azure App Service Issue

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I am unable to rum Docker Container Registry on the Azure App service. I have a flask app and the following is the Dockerfile of it:-

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# copy project
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["gunicorn", "-w", "4", "-b", "0.0.0.0:80", "app:app"]
```

I have deployed the docker image on the Container Registry. I have also set WEBSITES_PORT to 80 under App Service -> Application Settings.
Even after doing that, I get the following error:-

```
  ERROR - Container XYZ didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start.
```

I have tried running it locally and it works fine. But, it just does not seem to work on the Azure App service. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check the Azure log stream, if you get a timeout error on application logs then increase the timeout for the application.

Comment: add a new application setting — WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT:1500 , this will keep the container on until our application is started and ready to serve.[Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/storage/attachments/41422-demo5.png)

Comment: Hi @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT, thanks for your response. However, there is no timeout error. I still tried setting WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT to 1500. I still get the error:- didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue in the code you posted but to verify, here is a configuration for a Flask app with a Gunicorn server that works on a containerized Azure App Service:

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask
    
app = Flask(__name__)
    
@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello World!</p>"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
ADD app.py app.py
ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind=0.0.0.0:80", "app:app"]
```

requirements.txt

```
flask
gunicorn
```

I assume you selected "Docker Container" when you created the Azure App Service?

[image]

And then simply chose your image?

[image]

Comment: Hi Christian,  I tried using the code you provided. Also, used the same Dockerfile and requirements.txt. Currently, only WEBSITES_PORT is set to 80. Unfortunately, I still get the 'Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80' error. I have kept the same settings of the app service as you have mentioned in your screenshot. On my Local machine, the code works perfectly fine. But on Azure App Service, it throws the port error.

Comment: Did you try to run exactly the same code as in my app.py? I just want to verify if the problem may be caused by exhausted resources.